# A tuple with objects of different shapes

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, tuples, typeerror

I need to push objects to an array, but the objects have different shapes. Something like this:

```
const credentials = [
  {
    service: 'Service1',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    key: 25
  },
  {
    service: 'Service2',
    ip: '192.168.1.2',
    name: 'Person',
    url: 'test.com'
  },
]
```

I tried to [use Tuple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1jyv.png), but I receive an error when I try to access properties.

**EDIT:** The problem is not necessarily pushing objects, is access, basically, the problem is with the type definition

Comment: use a Map. Have an Array of Map's

Comment: To push? Sorry I forgot to mention that the problem is not necessarily pushing objects, is access, basically, the problem is with the type definition

Comment: If this is an array where different objects can be added in arbitrary places, you need some way to distinguish the shapes before accessing a property. Can you please post the type definitions you tried to use?

Comment: Exactly. The code: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGEoQCYXMOAGwEZkBvAWAChlkBbAazAC5kBnMKUAcwG5raEOnGCFWHLiD4DkcAA7AA+gwgBPcZx78qAX2rVQkWIhQYsufEQBM5GYxbtNU7bURI2bRWAD2KkBslpGmQAVzZoRWBsAK0ZLBgsNgALL188GOdqPSoDcGh4JDRMHDwwAkIAZltg+2YJHhlwwkIeRTk4KDAQCKiMoNo6AHdPOBCwFJ8-Pu0dIA) @Bergi

Comment: @Vinicius That playground seems incomplete, it contains only type definitions but no code that uses them or tries to push objects to an array

Comment: If you want to `push` to the array, a tuple type makes no sense. Try using an array with a discriminated union instead.